# How to remove 'manage contacts' from google oauth consent screen?

Tags: oauth

I have implemented google oauth for my website but on the consent screen it is showing a third option of 'Manage Contacts'. I beleive this will scare away users. On developer console I was not able to find any screen from where I can change this. Please help.
[image]